# My Answer got downvoted and I updated it. Will downvotes go away?

Tags: discussion, support

I answered [What is the difference between hosts and hosts.deny?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800750/what-is-the-difference-between-hosts-and-hosts-deny/800760) with a one-line answer (first line of my answer, basically RTFM).

I got downvoted to -2 for my answer.

I Edited and improved my answer (IMHO).

Will the downvotes go away? Will the downvoters be told I changed my answer?

If the answers are (No, No), why would one update one's own bad answer?

Comment: Surprised to see a user with moderator tools (i.e 10k) asking this question!

Answer (score 4):

Answer is `No` and `No`. Downvotes are given by users and only users can remove those. Alternative is to delete the answer. You can also ask moderator or higher-rep user for review.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking "why would one update one's own bad answer?"

To state it simply: I rather don't have a bad answer with my name under it.

Apart from this there is another point: When you edit your answer the post will (as having new activity) be moved forward and more people will see your (now hopefully good) answer - so you will collect more reputation than you had lost before.